# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, exc-bad-access

In my app is a very very tedious error!
Nearly every time I build my app I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"-error!
That's okay, there can be a error, but if I try to build the app again, the error comes back, but on another line of code!!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480) {
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
} else {
    mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main4er" bundle:nil];
}

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; // HERE THE ERROR COMES SOMETIMES
return YES; }
```

I don't know where my fault is! I don't work with release, retain - I turned it off when I started developing the app!

Sometimes the error comes at lines like this:

```
UILabel * labelNiederlage = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(243, -2, 40, 26)];
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is ARC enabled in your project?

Comment: Just from curiosity. Go to `Project Target -> General` what is selected as `Main Interface` ?

Comment: Main is the Main Interface.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, if you are using storyboards, you can safely remove these lines

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height <= 480) {
        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    } else {
        mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main4er" bundle:nil];
    }
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController]];
```

It is also bad idea to make two storyboards for different screen heights since you can make elements of dynamic height in single storyboard

Probably your app fails because you don't use property, `mainStoryboad` have to be `(strong, nonatomic)` and you have to have strong  reference to a pointer (which automatically maintained when you use properties, i. e. `self.mainStoryboad`;

Comment: The dynamic screen height option doesn't work for me! It always takes the same height for 4" and 3,5"...
Does IBOutlets have to be strong, too?

Comment: Nope, IB outlets have to be weak. Well, screen template in IB is static, but when you run in different simulators, system applies Autoresizing masks or Autolayout constraints, depending on system you are using. Probably you have to read about one of these systems, and you'll see that it is much simpler to have one storyboard (ipad vs iphone is different case)

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to tell from a few lines of codes. As Dig said, your storyboard may not be retained. Still, I would recommend the following approach :

1) make sure you don't have a dangling pointer somewhere which is likely to be the root of your problem.

-> Have a look at what you do with your storyboard (and others!). Do you retain it somehow somewhere ? By convention, the storyboardWithName returns an autoreleased object. You may need to retain it yourself if nothing does it for you. Same for others.

-> run instruments with zombie mode on, you may spot something funny. I recommend to enable this and the retain count

2) if you can't spot it with this, build a simple test case in a new project with a nearly empty storyboard. This might help working out what's wrong here.

3) Compare your code with a working example. There are loads of them. Just get one and spot the differences.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you come across this type of errors you could use **Zombie Objects** to get a hint what is going wrong.

Go to **"YourProjectName"**(right next to stop btn)**->Edit Scheme->Enable Guard Malloc** and **Enable Zombi Objects**. Then just set brake point and see what going on.

It's quite expensive operation though, so you probably want to turn it off when you fix your problem.

Regards,

HrisTo

Comment: I started it, but I don't know how to interpret it! I'm just loading articles and per article one image...
All Heap & Anonymous VM has 57,07 MB living bytes and 104,58 overall bytes, this is bad, I think, but I never worked with Instruments, so I don't know what to do now! :/